# Configuring Bounce for different object in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collider

I have a **ball** object with physics material that set bounce to 1.0 and friction to 0.0

Now, I have 2 colliders:

**Wall-A**: Made with Brick and

**Wall-B:** Made with Rubber

How should I configure **Wall-B** to bounce slow but **Wall-A** to bounce fast?

Comment: you fire up google, punch in "unity physics material tutorial" and find this https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-materials

Comment: @Arshia001 no, that would be really offensive. but now that i read it, it comes across way worse than i intended. sry OP.

Answer (score 0):

For **Wall-B**  to make bounce slow need to check the values of **Dynamic Friction** and **Static Friction** according to the need of user and Same as For **Wall-A** we need to check the value of **Dynamic Friction** and **Static Friction** of physic material according to the need .